# How to stop geany from executing a script

Tags: geany

In the geany editor, I can run my programs by configuring the execute command.

Now and then I like to interrupt an executing script without closing/killing the editor. I haven't figured out, how to do this from inside the editor.

Using geany on Linux, I could of course search the process with ps and kill it from the shell. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you choose `Execute programs in the VTE` (if not, the running terminal is seperated from the editor, then just close the running terminal, and the editor still there).

Now, moving cursor to terminal (inside Geany), then `ctrl+c`.

You can set shortcut keys for switch cursor to  terminal (inside Geany) by `Edit->Preferences->Keybindings->Switch to VTE`; or you can set it in the file `keybindings.conf` in folder `~/.config/geany`.